# Creating a file if it doesn't exists, then opening the file in RW mode

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, io

In Python I'm trying to create a file if it doesn't exist, then open it in read/write mode. The most succinct way I've been able to express this is with the following:

```
with os.fdopen(os.open('foo.bar', os.O_RDWR | os.O_CREAT), "r+") as f:
    # read file contents...
    # append new stuff...
```

Is there a better way to do this? Should I just check `if not os.path.exists('foo.bar')`, create the file if it doesn't exist, then open the file in "r+" mode?

In essence:

```
 if not os.path.exists('foo.bar'):
      os.makedirs('foo.bar') # or open('foo.bar', 'a').close()
 with open('foo.bar', "r+") as f:
    # read file contents...
    # append new stuff...
```

Comment: Always add the generic python tag, btw

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Good point; appreciate it!

Comment: Hm, couldn't you just use `'a+'` mode, which will create it if it doesn't exist, and positions the stream at the end?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Using f.seek(0), right? For some reason I didn't like the way it looked, but I think I'm just weird lol. Probably best to do that

Comment: But are you only reading from the file so you can append to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second option is a bit iffy, as testing before the open leave you open to race conditions if your program isn't the only user / consumer of the file.

I would probably use a+ and seek back to the beginning

```
with open("file", "a+") as f:
    f.seek(0)
    f.read()
    ...
```

Something else to consider I guess would be to just ditch the python file object and use os directly.

```
fd = os.open("file", os.O_RDWR | os.O_CREAT)
buffer = os.read(fd)
new_data = b'stuff to append'
os.write(fd, new_data)
os.close(fd)

etc
```

This would require a bunch more code as you'll have to keep track of file handles manually which may be more of a pain than what you're doing with the "with" context management.

Answer (score 1):

The main question is whether you want to truncate the file if it already exists.

If so, then do:

```
with open("filename", "w+") as f:
  f.write("Hello, world")
```

Otherwise, do what [juanpa.arrivillaga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5014455/juanpa-arrivillaga) suggested:

```
with open("filename", "a+") as f
  f.write("Hello, world")
```

The "a+" opens the file and starts at the end of the file. Check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) for more on how this works.